# Python group by three lists with itertools

Tags: python

I'm trying to use `groupby` function from `itertools` library. For group 2 lists the next code work perfectly:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

date = ['2019/07/25', '2019/07/25', '2019/07/27', '2019/07/28', '2019/07/28', '2019/07/28', '2019/07/28', '2019/07/28']
count1 = [1, 3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1]
count2 = [2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

def group_data(date, count):
    group = []
    for k, g in groupby(zip(date, count), itemgetter(0)):
        group.append((k, sum(list(list(zip(*g))[1]))))
    sorted(group)
    return group

print(group_data(date, count1))
[('2019/07/25', 3), ('2019/07/27', 3), ('2019/07/28', 3)]
```

But how to rewrite it for 3 lists?

`group_data(date, count1, count2)` should return:

```
[('2019/07/25', 3, 4), ('2019/07/27', 3, 4), ('2019/07/28', 3, 4)]
```

In other words I want to get the same result as implementing `pandas` function `groupby` but using `itertools` and get a list of sets:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':date,'count1':count1,'count2':count2})
df.groupby('date')['count1', 'count2'].sum()


   date     count     count2        
2019/07/25    4         3
2019/07/27    4         3
2019/07/28    4         3
```

Comment: can you explain the logic of the code too please? Why is that the expected output?

Comment: The function groups lists by date and applying the summary function for counts with the same date

Comment: The line `sorted(group)` doesn't do nothing. Maybe you meant `group.sort()`?

Comment: Can you elaborate? "applying the summary function for counts with the same date" Actually walk through the example with that. you can edit into the question. Essentially, What did you want to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just need it for 3 lists then this works:

```
def group_data(date, count1, count2):
    group = []
    for k, g in groupby(zip(date, count1, count2), itemgetter(0)):
        g12 = list(zip(*g))
        group.append((k, sum(list(g12[1])), sum(list(g12[2]))))
    sorted(group)
    return group
```

But I think it could be much simplier.

In case you need for n lists:

```
def group_data(date, *counts):
    group = []
    for k, g in groupby(zip(date, *counts), itemgetter(0)):
        gzip = list(zip(*g))
        group.append((k, *list((sum(l) for l in gzip[1:]))))
    sorted(group)
    return group
```

Comment: Nice! This is the result that I wanted to get. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For **any** number of lists:

```
from itertools import groupby

dates = ['2019/07/25', '2019/07/25', '2019/07/27', '2019/07/28', '2019/07/28', '2019/07/28', '2019/07/28', '2019/07/28']
count1 = [1, 3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1]
count2 = [2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]
count3 = [3, 2, 5, 1, 10, 3, 0, 1]

def sum_group_data(dates, *counts):
    res = []
    size = len(counts)
    for k, g in groupby(zip(dates, *counts), key=lambda x: x[0]):
        group = list(g)
        if len(group) == 1:
            res.append(group[0])
        else:
            res.append((group[0][0], *[sum(j[i+1] for j in group) for i in range(size)]))
    return res

print(sum_group_data(dates, count1, count2, count3))
```

The output:

```
[('2019/07/25', 4, 3, 5), ('2019/07/27', 4, 3, 5), ('2019/07/28', 4, 3, 15)]
```

Answer (score -1):

you don't need itertools for this task.
It can be simply done by using the zip function

```
date= ['2019/07/25', '2019/07/25', '2019/07/27', 2019/07/28','2019/07/28','2019/07/28', '2019/07/28', '2019/07/28']
count1 = [1, 3, 4, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1]
count2 = [2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0]

print(zip(date,count1,count2)
```

Comment: But thats not what op wants... He wants to group the same dates together and not have duplicates.  Read the question and the expected output more carefully

Comment: I think it would be best if you delete this answer as it clearly doesn't answer the question, on top of that it has 2 syntax errors, on top of that there is already an accepted answer